# Given $ X \sim U[-1, 1]$ find the PDF of $Y=\frac{1}{1+X}$ - how to divide to ranges?

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

Regarding the following problem:

> Given $ X \sim U[-1, 1]$ find the PDF of $Y=\frac{1}{1+X}$

So:

$F_Y(t)=P(Y\leq t)=P(\frac{1}{1+X}\leq t)=P(X> \frac{1-t}{t}) = 1 - P(X\leq \frac{1-t}{t})$

Now I need to seprate the different cases for t - and this is the point I always fail to do. I tried to plot the function:

[image: plot]

And to extract information from there, and the only ranges I could think of were $t<0$ and $t\geq 0$ which is probably incorrect.

Could someone please explain me how to approach such problems? 
Thanks

Comment: Why not just use a change of variables ?

$Y=\frac{1}{1+X}\implies x=\frac{1-y}{y}$ and $-1<x<1\implies 0<1+x<2\implies y>\frac{1}{2}$.

So the pdf of $Y$ is

$$f_Y(y)=f_X\left(\frac{1-y}{y}\right)\left|\frac{dx}{dy}\right|\mathbf1_{y>1/2}=\cdots$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Observe that $1+X \in [0,2]$ so that $Y \in [1/2,+\infty)$ almost surely. This means that for $t \leq 1/2$ you have $F_Y(t) = 0$. The expression you wrote holds for $t>1/2$.

**In general**, your procedure is correct. You just have to take care of where your random variable takes values. If, for example, $Z \in [a,b]$ then you'll have $F_Z(x) = 0$ for $x < a$ and $F_Z(x) = 1$ for $x \geq b$.

Also, remind to take care of what happens when you divide. In this case, there's a point where you divide by $t$ but that would change the sign of the inequality. However, we are sure that $t \geq 1/2$ for the previous discussion, so there's no need to make this distinction now.

**Side note:** how did I calculate the support of $Y$? I calculated the image of 
$$f(x) = \frac{1}{1+x}, \quad x \in 
[-1,1]$$
Since $f$ is decreasing and continuous, it suffices to observe that $$f(1)=1/2$$
$$\lim_{x \to -1^+} f(x) = + \infty$$
to get the desired image.

Comment: So these are the only two ranges? because when $t\geq\frac{1}{2}$ it seems like it behaves different then $0<t<\frac{1}{2}$

Comment: How does it behave differently? What happens for those ranges?

Comment: If $t\geq \frac{1}{2}$ then $-1 \leq \frac{1-t}{t} \leq 2 $ , which is in the range where $F_X(\frac{1-t}{t}) = \frac{t+1}{3}$

Comment: Sorry, actually, I made a slight mistake in the calculation. I'll edit this.

Comment: Sure :) could you please just specify the steps for finding the corresponding supports? I found it using intuition only, but it sucks

Comment: And oops it should be $F_X(\frac{1-t}{t})=\frac{t+1}{2}$

Comment: @superuser123, I'm a bit busy at work right now, but I'll add those steps later :)

Comment: @superuser123: done, hope it's more clear now!